# Month 13 is Out of Bounds, TIC SSL Trust Error, and Error -1202 when loading HTTPS url

Tags: ios, swift, crash, alamofire

I'm loading a URL to a Text Label using Alamofire, and occasionally my app crashes with the only indication in the logs being a WebFilter issue. This occurs on URLs that have loaded successfully previously, and continue to do so afterwards.

My info.plist is set to allow arbitrary loads, and the domain in question (snopes.com) is also excluded. I suspect there's an issue with the site's profile, but I'm seeing Month 13 out of bounds errors having to do with other issues with dates having the month of December in them. What I'm not seeing is a "fix" or workaround.

Here's how I'm loading the URL and displaying it:

```
Alamofire.request(articleURL).responseString { response in
    print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
    if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
      self.article = utf8Text
      print("HTML: \(String(describing: self.article))")
    } else {
      self.article = "Sorry, trouble loading Article"
    }
    if let article = self.article {
      if var attrArticle = article.html2AttributedString {
        //for low vision
        if let lowVision = self.lowVision {
          print("Low Vision?: \(lowVision)")
          attrArticle = attrArticle.changeHTMLFont(attrArticle)
        }
        self.articleLbl.attributedText = attrArticle
      }
    } else {
      self.articleLbl.text = "Sorry, trouble loading Article"
    }
  }
```

Comment: What line of code does the crash occur on? There is nothing in this code that references a date.

Comment: Crashing on `print("HTML: \(String(describing: self.article))"` - I'm sure a date comes in with the SSL certificate